# Close second window to go back to first window

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm developing some programe in python.
Now i can open a second window but now i will go back to my first window.
My problem is when i push the close button my first and second window close.
And i will that only my second window closed.

My code:
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from forms.runtime_form import Ui_runtime_form
    import datetime
    import time

```
"""
    The main class
    First window
"""
class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        self.run_mode = 0

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = Ui_runtime_form()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.main_thread = main_thread(self)
        self.main_thread.start()
        self.main_thread.update_date_time.connect(self.update_date_time)

        if self.run_mode == 0:

            Uit = QtGui.QPushButton('Uit', self)    
            Uit.move(20,650)
            Uit.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

            #button to open second window
            bla = QtGui.QPushButton('bla', self)    
            bla.move(150,650)
            bla.clicked.connect(self.child)

    #open second window
    def child(self):

        test = Example(self)
        test.showFullScreen()

    def update_date_time(self):

        #some other code

#Second window    
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        Uit = QtGui.QPushButton('Uit', self)
        Uit.clicked.connect(self.sluit) 
        Uit.move(150,50)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Modbus Domotica - Touchscreen')    
        self.show()

    #Close second window    
    def sluit(self):
        sys.exit(0)

class main_thread(QtCore.QThread):

    update_date_time = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, layout):

        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):

        while True:

            self.update_date_time.emit()

            time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    QtGui.QApplication.setPalette(QtGui.QApplication.style().standardPalette())

    myapp = StartQT4()
    myapp.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have solve the problem, i must use "QDialog".

Answer (score 2):

Of course both windows close, you are exiting Python!

```
#Close second window    
def sluit(self):
    sys.exit(0)
```

Instead, try -

```
def sluit(self):
    self.close()
```